# CSS vertical drop down menu expands and closes automatically

Tags: html, css

My vertical css drop down menu works fine in all browsers except IE where the menus open but close down automatically.

Here is the link to the page:

http://telugugreetings.net/vertical.html

Kindly help me

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is not working. The page seems to work fine in IE as far back as IE8

Comment: I think issue comes with ie7

Comment: For me ur page content is not loading properly in IE8 . Is that d issue ?

Comment: It opens properly in IE8 but when expanding any of the main links, the sub links open (dropdown) but immediately close down.